# Word Choice: Who or Whom?

Tags: word-choice

I am doing some proofreading and have a question. In the following line of a poem, should it be who or whom? It's talking about monsters and the fact that they have a lot of options as to who they choose to eat so they can grow larger.

The line:

So many decisions of who to choose so they can grow,

Comment: Monsters, and poets, have free rein to break rules. Proofreading a poem is one thankless task.

Comment: "Limitations are deadening; to limit oneself is a form of suicide;, to limit another is a form of murder; to limit poetry is a Hiroshima of the human spirit. DANGER! RADIATION!" - T. Robbins

Comment: @JohnLawler There are pros and cons in this philosophy: I am being reminded of a columnist who once wrote, in contradiction to William Cowper, that variety is the spice of death.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct most of the time but "whom" is  formal. In the words of CoGEL (1985 edition, § 6.35), *whom* can be avoided altogether in informal style.

When the pronoun follows a preposition and that it is a prepositional complement the form "whom" is more regularly used. Fot instance, you say normally

- "This is the person *who* you spoke *to*.",

but

- "This is the person *to who* you spoke."

is not correct (unacceptable in British English).

In the words of CoGEL (1985 edition, § 6.35), the reason is that there is a stylistic incompatibility between the preposition + relative pronoun construction (*to whom*), which is rather formal, and the use of *who* rather than *whom* as prepositional complement (*who … to*), which is informal.

However, your sentence is not of the sort discussed above; "who" is not the prepositional complement of "of", instead "whom to choose so they can grow" is.  Consequently, "who" is a possibility, albeit the style will be informal.

- So many decisions of who to choose so they can grow

*Formal*

- So many decisions of whom to choose so they can grow

Comment: Broadly speaking I agree with this, but *strictly speaking* I'm pretty certain pedants wouldn't accept your first example *This is the person **who** you spoke **to***. The "formal rules" are unaffected by the fact of moving the preposition to the end of the utterance. It's just that *in practice* we've tended to abandon ***whom*** in almost all contexts except those where it's immediately preceded by ***to***. But to true grammarians, it should be *This is the person **who** you spoke to*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, you invoke true grammar, but what do you think about this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+you+spoke+to%2C+whom+you+spoke+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwho%20you%20spoke%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhom%20you%20spoke%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwho%20you%20spoke%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhom%20you%20spoke%20to%3B%2Cc0), admitting you consider as true actual usage?

Comment: I think that chart confirms my point. In Victorian times, "strict grammar" was more rigorously applied, so it was nearly always ***whom** you spoke to*, not ***who***. In principle the ***who/whom*** distinction is *only* determined by whether it's subject or object. But in *practice* that's too complicated a rule for most ordinary people, so they just decide on the basis of whether the relative pronoun is preceded by preposition ***to*** or not. So people almost *always* get it "right" so long as they avoid allowing the preposition to be moved to the end of the utterance...

Comment: ...see [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+who+you+spoke%2Cto+whom+you+spoke&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20whom%20you%20spoke%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cto%20whom%20you%20spoke%3B%2Cc0) showing that if it's re-sequenced to ***to whom** you spoke*, the "incorrect" version ***to who** you spoke* is so rare it doesn't even figure on the usage chart.

Answer (score 1):

***Who*** is a relative pronoun that works much like a subjective pronoun. On the other hand, ***Whom*** is a relative pronoun that works much like an objective pronoun. They mean the same thing and it is just a technicality. Using ***who*** in spoken English is fine.

To make it simpler, I always suggest students replace ***who*** or ***whom*** by ***he*** or ***him***. If the word ***him*** is appropriate, then whom, otherwise ***who***.

Examples:

***Who*** picks ***whom***. -> He picks him.
You sent the messages to ***whom***. -> You sent the messages to him.

There are exceptions, but in general you should use whom after prepositions:

The children to ***whom*** I gave the toys.
***Who*** is behind ***whom***?
At ***whom*** are you mad?
With ***whom*** did you go out? More commonly Spoken -> ***Who*** did you go out with?

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

> So many decisions whom to choose so they can grow
>
> or
>
> So many decisions, whom to choose so they can grow